# Spring configuration file defined in multiple place

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Suppose I have created an spring application with following configurations

#### First::

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springweb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springweb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Spring will look for springweb-servlet.xml file. Then it will read all the bean difination from the file and creates bean objects
Here only single application context is created.

#### Second::

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springweb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springweb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/service-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Here first spring reads all the beans definations from service-context.xml file, which is the root spring context.
Then it reads all the bean definations from the springweb-servlet.xml file, which is the child spring context/WebApplicationContext.
Then all the merge the two parent-child context into one and create spring beans objects

#### Third::

What if I define the springweb-servlet.xml file in both place.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springweb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springweb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/springweb-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/service-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Nothing is being merged there are 2 separated context where the child can lookup beans from the parent. They aren't merged. In your third sample all the beans in the `springweb-servlet.xml` will be loaded twice.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks for the information. Can you please elaborate it in more details what actually happens when same configuration is loaded twice. Does it means the configuration it loaded first time is discarded. If not does it means same bean is created 2nd time. I just want to know that actually happens.

Comment: What isn't clear about that all the beans are duplicated? The configuration is loaded twice, hence everything is in memory twice... It takes up additional memory and weird things can (and will) happen especially when AOP, transactions and/or other resources are involved.